# Taylor expansion in Lattice Boltzmann Method derivation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lattice-model, kinetic-theory

Currently I'm trying to understand Lattice Boltzmann Method for 
solving CFD problems. In its derivation [BGK approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhatnagar%E2%80%93Gross%E2%80%93Krook_operator) is used to get rid of complicated collision integral. But when they come to descritization of equilibrium function (Maxwellian):
$$
f^{eq} = \cfrac{\rho}{(2\pi RT)^{D/2}}\exp\left[-\cfrac{(\bf e - u)^2}{2RT}\right]
$$
they use following Taylor expansion:
$$
f^{eq} \approx \cfrac{\rho}{(2\pi RT)^{D/2}}\exp\left[-\cfrac{\bf e^2}{2RT}\right]
\left(1 + \cfrac{\bf e \cdot u}{RT} + \cfrac{(\bf e \cdot u)^2}{2(RT)^2}
- \cfrac{\bf u^2}{2RT}\right)
$$
which is valid for low Mach numbers and constant temperature.
So my question is: why do we use this expansion? why original expression of $f^{eq}$
is not used? And where does condition $Ma \ll 1$ come from? Do we need the condition just for expansion or it is needed somewhere else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So, in the future I would recommend (as a polite request) providing definitions for each variable so that a reader is not left sifting through the internet trying to deconvolve the symbols.

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_Boltzmann_methods), which used the same notation (and failed to clearly define many of the variables), we have the following definitions:
$\mathbf{e}$ $\equiv$ microscopic velocity;
$\mathbf{u}$ $\equiv$ macroscopic velocity (i.e., Avg. or bulk flow velocity which is often derived from the first velocity [moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) of the distribution function);
D $\equiv$ number of degrees of freedom;
R $\equiv$ gas constant;
T $\equiv$ Avg. temperature (i.e., derived from second velocity moment of the distribution function); and
$\rho$ $\equiv$ number(?) density.

In order to do this expansion, you would need to assume something like:
$$
\frac{u}{R \ T} \sim small
$$
which is where the small Mach number argument would come from (since RT $\propto$ thermal speed and/or sound speed, depending on definitions used).  [**Side Note** I am a little bothered by the idea of a dyadic product in an exponent.  What does an exponential tensor physically imply?]  The other reason to make this assumption would be to decrease the total number of computations necessary.  If you set up a high Mach number warm, dense flow, you would need to resolve several scales increasing your computations (the theorists/simulationists on this site would be able to clarify this in more detail).

As for why one would use such an expansion, I imagine it has to do with computational efficiency or ease.  It is easier to compute a simple numerical fraction than the exponential of the square of a difference.  Typically, one does a [Taylor approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) like this to simplify the equation.  The simplified equation can often be interpreted in a physically intuitive sense, whereas the original form may be too obscure to understand physically.

For instance, think of the [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier-Stokes_equations) and how would you try to understand the full system.  Without approximations (e.g., assume [inviscid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inviscid_flow) or [incompressible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow) flow) the full equation can be very difficult to deal with, even for computers (7 dimensions [3 spatial, 3 velocity/momentum, and 1 time] for each computation).  That is a lot of computations for just one time step.